# Adding path of downloaded Python to Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, solidity

Just gone through the process of setting up python and all the installs using cmd and now i want to use

> brownie bake

To clone some code and it gives errors as it cant locate brownie... I've set environmental variables for the path (that's how I got it to work in cmd)... I've installed the python extension and chose the python.exe file in my new install in the compiler by clicking the bottom left... How can I make visual studios Code use only the python and all library's I installed?

if i run

> python

in the terminal it opens up windows store for python install but i can run my version by using

> py

Comment: Have you looked in Visual Studio's documentation? I'm sure something about what you want to know is in it. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First,** Disable the `python` command to open the windows store:

Search `Manage app execution aliases` and unselect `App Installer` of Python:

[image]

**Second,** You need to check which python you have installed your packages to:

[image]

And make sure in the VSCode you have selected the right interpreter(In the following picture, they are different).

[image]

Comment: @Hyperzee Please [accept and upvote my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solves your question. Don't hesitate to let me know if you have any other problems.

Comment: Please stop [begging for upvotes/accepts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167155/284827). I've flagged comments that you've posted on about 25 of your answers since May 20th where you've posted the same message. If a user wants to upvote or accept your answer - or not - that's their choice.

Comment: @Wai Ha Lee haha, got it.